# Ember model.get() not returning values or binding to template properly

Tags: templates, ember.js

I have a route which populates a model property via the `.store.query()` method inside an RSVP hash:

```
model(params, transition) { 
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        myData: this.store.query('table-datum', parameters)
    });
}
```

This returns a promise and seems to get data into my store according to the Ember inspector, I see the correct number of rows and they all have attributes with data populated.

I then have a simple component template inside my main view template with an `each` block to display the output:

```
    {{#each data as |result|}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{result.prop1}}</td>
            <td>{{result.prop2}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

I'm passing the property to my component like this:

```
        <div id="tableContainer">
            {{result-table data=model.myData}}  
        </div>
```

But for some reason the template binds the correct number of rows, but isn't correctly accessing the `prop1` and `prop2` bits of the class (so I just get 20 or so blank table rows)

If I try to output just `{{result}}` in my template it looks like this:

```
<client@model:table-datum::ember574:1>
```

I'm pretty sure the data is there somewhere just it seems like my template isn't accessing the properties for some reason.

Any ideas as to where to look for this one?

EDIT: Logging the `result` object looks almost right, but not quite:

[image]

Expanding the internal model shows some data, but also says 'Empty object' which seems kind of wrong to me!

[image]

EDIT: If it helps I have a controller function, which gets the `model.myData` and operates on it, which gives me the result I expect:

```
getMax() {
    let max = _.max(this.get('model.myData'),'aField').aField;
    console.log(max); // logs 41 as I expect
    return max;
}
```

Comment: What do you get in console if you log the result? `{{ log result }}`

Comment: I get what seems to be an Ember class with values inside it, but it also weirdly says 'Empty object' in a few places, will update the question with the images

Comment: `myData: this.store.query('table-datum', parameters)` is invalid, is that your real code? Returning promises in properties/computed properties is highly discouraged, any chance you can move the query to the route?

Comment: That's my real code where parameters is an object of query string params I wanted passing to my end point. It generates a valid HTTP request which returns valid JSON. I'm 99.99% that's not the problem.

Comment: Your code seems fine... THe only reason I can see is that maybe you are not accessing the properties correctly. How do you access the properties in your component with `result.LUF` or `result.luf` ?

Comment: It looks model mapping between model & server response may not be done correctly. Your model(table-datum) may not contains field you used in template. Could you pls show model file?.

Comment: Can you post you `models/table-datum.js` file please? Everything that you are doing seems correct, but my hunch is that there is a mixup getting the data properly into the store. Also, what serializer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your doing within your routes model?

```
model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        myData: this.store.query('table-datum', parameters)
    }).then(function(results) { 
        return results; 
    }).catch(function(error) { 
        throw error;
    });
},
setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(...arguments);
    Ember.set(controller, 'myData', model.myData);
}
```

Then within the template I would access myData.

Comment: The `then` and `catch` cases in your example are redundant

Comment: Doesn't he have to access `model.myData` within the template?

Comment: @Vis I am doing what you've written without the .then/catch because I understood them to be redundant as @DanMcClain says. 

Additionally I've not explicitly set a controller property to the model.myData as all my other hash properties work ok and are accessible (I use `findAll()` with those)

Comment: @torazaburo I am passing `model.myData` as a property called `data` to a child component. This works in all my other hash properties on the model in several other (and even this) component(s).

Comment: myData would be the model.

Comment: @Visualjeff in this case, `myData` would be a property on the model hash. I have several other properties in the same model.